# Consuming pod logs on Openshift with Filebeat

Tags: docker, logging, openshift, filebeat

I've configured `filebeat` instance, and when it was running without errors, I've figured out, it does nothing.

I've found in log the following line:

```
 INFO   log/input.go:138    Configured paths: [/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log]
```

Quick check and I've found out, that the difference between `openshift` and pure `docker` is, that in `docker` the directories under `/var/lib/docker/containers` contains log files and under `openshift` they don't.

How should I configure `filebeat` to work under `openshift`?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK OpenShift also log out container logs as  `/var/lib/docker/containers/<hash>/*-json.log` format, refer [Viewing available container logs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/host_preparation.html#viewing-available-container-logs)
 for more details. If you can not find out at the directory, your `docker` `log driver` might be configured as `journald`, it can check from `/etc/sysconfig/docker`.

```
OPTIONS=' --selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=False'
```

Then you should change `journald` to `json-file` for logging into `/var/lib/docker/containers/<hash>/*-json.log`.

```
OPTIONS=' --selinux-enabled --log-driver=json-file --signature-verification=False'
```

you need to restart the `docker.service` for taking effect.

Comment: OK at least I know what is happening. I would prefer less invasive solution, but it looks like there's no build-in support for journald for filebeat.

Comment: I understand you to prefer less changes for the configuration, what version is the OCP ? As of v3.9 the default log driver of docker is changed as json-file, so you can usually use the filebeat by your configuration you provided above. Refer https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/release_notes/ocp_3_9_release_notes.html#ocp-37-journald-system-logs